# RuntimeError: You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm making a dashboard in python, using flask.
It needs to run three tasks: flask, `datastream_handler()`, and `dashboard_handler()`. One of these tasks, `datastream_handler()`, is required to be an async function.

I've used threading to allow the tasks to run at the same time, (flask and `dashboard_handler()` are threads, `datastream_handler()` is run from the main thread).

`dashboard_handler()` and `datastream_handler()` start up and run perfectly, and flask appears to start but when I visit the webpage it gives me an error in terminal:
`RuntimeError: You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly.`

I'm confused, because I have awaited the async function (datastream_handler) directly?

I've tried switching it around so that flask is the main thread, and `datastream_handler()` is started as a threading.Thread (using asyncio.run to start the async function from a non-async function). However, this just gave the same error.

I looked up this error and a couple of people had the same error with Django and requests-html, but their findings were specific to their respective framework and couldn't be applied to flask.

Here is my code:

`datastream_handler` and `dashboard_handler` are in different files;
`dashboard_handler` is just a normal synchronous function with a while loop and `datastream_handler` is an async function which currently only contains a while loop with print and asyncio.sleep, for testing purposes.

I don't think the contents of these functions are causing the errors, but correct me if I am wrong

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
socket = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
async def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

def start_flask():
    socket.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
        
async def main():

    q = Queue() #queue for data transfer
    threading.Thread(target=dashboard_handler, args=(q,), daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=start_flask, daemon=True).start()

    await datastream_handler(q)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

If anyone can help I would be very grateful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the reason putting `Flask` in thread? `Flask` app should be initiated in the main thread.

About this error,
`RuntimeError: You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly.`

I think this come from 2 reasons:

1. You're running the Flask in thread
2. You're using `async def index()` which flask will turn it into threaded async using `asgiref`'s module `AsyncToSync` and at it can't be done in thread.

If you want to run 3 of those concurrently using thread and one of it is `asynchronous` maybe you can use `python-worker` [link](https://pypi.org/project/python-worker/)

1. Define `datastream_handler` and `dashboard_handler` as a worker

```
from worker import worker, async_worker

@async_worker
async def datastream_handler(q):
    ...

@worker
def dashboard_handler(q):
    ...
```

2. In your main file :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    asyncio.run(datastream_handler(q))
    dashboard_handler(q)
    socket.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

`datastream_handler` and `dashboard_handler` will automatically run as a thread.